# CURLOPT_URL codification with PREG_REPLACE value

Tags: php, curl, preg-replace

When i get the $url varible by preg_replace feedback it doesn't work but it i specify the $url value with the commented line it works. What's wrong in my code please? Many thanks.

```
$content = preg_replace('/(plugin_[^ ]+)/', getPlugin('$1'), $content);

function getPlugin($plugin) {
    $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/{$plugin}.php?language=en";
    //$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/plugin_contact.php?language=en";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Response: Not Found

The requested URL /plugin_contact.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
if (preg_match("/(plugin_[^ ]+)/", "$content", $match)) {
        $content = preg_replace('/(plugin_[^ ]+)/', getPlugin($match[0]), $content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't work because `getPlugin()` runs before `preg_replace()`. It is called with the literal `'$1'` as argument, there is nobody to replace `$1` with something else because `preg_replace()` is not involved.

I suppose you are refactoring a call to `preg_replace()` that uses the deprecated [`e`*`(PREG_REPLACE_EVAL)`* modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$content = preg_replace('/(plugin_[^ ]+)/e', 'getPlugin("$1")', $content);
```

In order to remove the `/e` modifier you can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/(plugin_[^ ]+)/', 'getPlugin', $content);

function getPlugin(array $matches) {
    $plugin = $matches[1];
    $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/{$plugin}.php?language=en";
    //$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/plugin_contact.php?language=en";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```